# Laravel: Set a cookie on successful login using a custom guard/attempt method

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-6

I am using a third party database for authentication. Everything is working *great* but now would like to set a cookie when a user has logged in.

As stated in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication):

> The attempt method will return true if authentication was successful. Otherwise, false will be returned.

This is what I am doing in my controller:

**MyLoginController.php**

```
$user = Auth::guard('foo')->attempt(['userid' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember); 

dd($user);

...

return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
```

Everything here is great. I'm getting `true` or `false` back as expected.

What I am trying to do is if the login is successful, set a cookie on the response. I need the user object back to get a value from. Something like this:

**MyLoginController.php**

```
$user = Auth::guard('foo')->attempt(['userid' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember); 

if ($user) {
    switch (App::environment()) {
        case 'local':
            $cookie = cookie('localCookieName', $user->token, 480);
            break;
        case 'development':
            $cookie = cookie('devCookieName', $user->token, 480);
            break;
        case 'production':
            $cookie = cookie('cookieName', $user->token, 480);
            break;
        default:
            //
            break;
       }

    return redirect()->intended(route('home'))->cookie($cookie);
}

return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
```

I am using a custom User Provider to authenticate my users - everything there is working great as well. I am getting the user, and saving any data to my local db if needed. I *thought* I might be able to just set the cookie in the UserProvider, but without doing `->cookie($cookie)` nothing is getting set.

The value of `$user->token` is coming back from my 3rd party authentication. So that's why I need to be able to access that value.

[Reading the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#cookies), it looks like I need to be setting cookie(s) on the response `->cookie($cookie)` or `withCookies($cookies)`.

This leads me to believe I need to set the cookie on my controller, but I'm not sure how to get the user object back since the `attempt` method only returns `true` or `false`.

How can I get the user object from within the `attempt` method? Maybe I am making thins incredibly difficult for myself and there is an easier way to set the cookie?

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Here is my `config/auth.php` file:

```
...

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'foo' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'foo',
    ],
],


...

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'foo' => [
        'driver' => 'foo',             // Using a 3rd party for auth.
        'model' => App\MyUser::class,  // User model for auth.
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Comment: why inside attempt?  are you still using a session guard?

Comment: I've updated my question to show my `config/auth.php` file. I am still using session guard yes.

Comment: what are you doing with this cookie you want to be attaching?

Comment: @lagbox it's kind of tricky - the 3rd party auth needs (what amounts to) a session token -- which is the value of the cookie passed back to it to get more info later on. Not idea, but that's what I have to work with. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attempt` does a login if the credentials are valid and correct for a User. So you can just get the user from the Request or the Auth guard, since they are logged in:

```
$user = $request->user();
$user = $request->auth('foo')->user();
$user = Auth::guard('foo')->user();
...
```

If you know that `attempt` passed, the User is also available via `getLastAttempted` on the session guard:

```
$user = Auth::guard('foo')->getLastAttempted();
```

Although you can use that I would not, as you have to check that `attempt` actually returned true before trusting this value. This holds the last user retrieved by credentials, which could not have been authenticated potentially, `attempt` returned false.

You do not have to directly be adding a cookie to the Response. In the Cookie section of the docs should be information about "queue"ing a cookie to automatically be attached to the outgoing Response:

```
Cookie::queue('name', 'value', $minutes);
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Responses - Attaching Cookies to Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses)

Comment: That worked - leveraging the "queable" method is the only thing I didn't try (go figure). I also found that using plain 'ol php `setcookie` worked. I was trying to use as much "Laravel way" as much as possible. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: just remember laravel encrypts cookies, so if you need to read it outside laravel that might be an issue